# Android App Crashing on Galaxy S8 Edge Only

Tags: android, xamarin

I have built the app which uses a webview in xamarin and I have tested them on many devices including the Galaxy S7 edge as I thought the reason for it not working is because of the Edge screen. However, it works fine on the S7 Edge but on the S8 Edge devices that I have tried them on, they instantly crash.

There's only two classes that I use:

MainActivity:

```
namespace APPNAME.Android
{
[Activity(Label = "APPNAME", Icon = "@drawable/icon", MainLauncher = 
false,
    ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | 
    ConfigChanges.Orientation)]

public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    WebView web_view;
    //private bool appeared;
    public class HelloWebViewClient : WebViewClient
    {
        public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, string 
        url)
        {
            view.LoadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        Window.RequestFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        web_view = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webview);
        web_view.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        web_view.SetWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());

        web_view.LoadUrl("http://link.com");
    }

    public override bool OnKeyDown(Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
    {
        if (keyCode == Keycode.Back && web_view != null)
        {
            try
            {
                if (web_view.CanGoBack())
                {
                    Log.Debug("StackOverflow", "Allow browser back");
                   // Toast.MakeText(this, "Going back", 
                    ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    web_view.GoBack();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error("StackOverflow", ex.Message);
            }
        }

        {
            //Log.Error("StackOv20erflow", "Null webview...");
            //StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
            //Finish();
            OnBackPressed();
        }
        //Log.Debug("StackOverflow", "Back button blocked");
        //Toast.MakeText(this, "Back button blocked", 
        ToastLength.Short).Show();
        return false;
    }

    public override void OnBackPressed()
    {
        Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ActionMain);
        startMain.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryHome);
        startMain.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
        StartActivity(startMain);

    }

}

}
```

Splash Screen:

```
namespace APPNAME.Android
{
[Activity(Theme = "@style/MyTheme.Splash", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = 
true)]
public class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    static readonly string TAG = "X:" + typeof(SplashActivity).Name;

    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, 
    PersistableBundle persistentState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        Log.Debug(TAG, "SplashActivity.OnCreate");
    }

    // Launches the startup task
    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        Task startupWork = new Task(() => { SimulateStartup(); });
        startupWork.Start();
    }

    // Simulates background work that happens behind the splash screen
    async void SimulateStartup()
    {
        //Log.Debug(TAG, "Performing some startup work that takes a bit of 
        time.");
        //await Task.Delay(1000); // Simulate a bit of startup work.
        //Log.Debug(TAG, "Startup work is finished - starting 
        MainActivity.");
        //StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context, 
        typeof(MainActivity)));
        await Task.Delay(4000);
        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.NewTask);
        StartActivity(intent);
    }
  }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:versionName="1.0.0.8" package="APPNAME.android" 
android:installLocation="auto" android:versionCode="8">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
<application android:label="APPNAME" android:icon="@drawable/Icon" 
android:debuggable="false"></application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

Not sure where to start fixing the issue as I don't know what's the cause of it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please include the logcat output also of the crash

Comment: What is in Logcat?

Comment: Do you have a crash reporter installed? if not, add one ;-)

Comment: I've published them to the store for internal testing, haven't tried to connect the device to the pc and launch it from here to do debugging. Don't have the device with me right now as the person with that device will only be here next week. Once I have it, I can get a log cat! @SamiKuhmonen

Comment: @SushiHangover Cool can you recommend one to use?

Comment: Personally I use Crashlytics,  but an "easy" to start with is Microsoft's:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile-center/crashes/ they have a Xamarin/C# wrapper: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile-center/sdk/getting-started/xamarin

Comment: Cool thanks a lot, will look into it on Monday when I can test that device again!

Comment: "What is in Logcat? " - I love .net developers trying to start mobile development without any bother to get to know how mobile device works LOL

Comment: logcat is pretty much indispensable when doing Android development.  It would probably tell you exactly what the problem is.  I typically use `monitor.exe` which has logcat filtering as well as the ability to take screen shots.  It's installed with the Android SDKs and can be found at `%ANDROID%\android-sdk\tools\lib\monitor-x86_64\monitor.exe`

Comment: @user1209216 I think you really misunderstood the question.

Comment: So it seems like the app started working on those devices after I pushed some updates last week. Not sure what made it work though as I haven't used any "fix" from online :/

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using `async void` ***unless in an event handler***. And also NEVER create a `new Task` and use `task.Start`

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

That said I would advise you create an event and handler in the `SplashActivity`

```
public class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity {

    static readonly string TAG = "X:" + typeof(SplashActivity).Name;

    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        Log.Debug(TAG, "SplashActivity.OnCreate");
    }

    // Launches the startup task
    private event EventHandler Starting = delegate { }
    protected override void OnResume() {
        base.OnResume();
        //subscribe to event
        Starting += Activity_Starting;
        //raise event
        Starting (this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    // Simulates background work that happens behind the splash screen
    async void Activity_Starting(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        //unsubscribe
        Starting -= Activity_Starting;
        //and carry on
        //Log.Debug(TAG, "Performing some startup work that takes a bit of time.");
        //await Task.Delay(1000); // Simulate a bit of startup work.
        //Log.Debug(TAG, "Startup work is finished - starting MainActivity.");
        //StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity)));
        await Task.Delay(4000);
        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.NewTask);
        StartActivity(intent);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just a word of caution to anyone implementing this.. if you += the event handler on every OnResume then you'll keep multiplying the number of times this runs, simply by navigating back to this activity.

Comment: @Le-royStaines even if it is unsubscribed in the event handler? (which it is by the way). By that stance the same would happen even without an event like how it was in the OP. Thoughts?

Comment: whoops I missed that you unsubscribed it in the handler. Though is that the most elegant way to do it? What if someone raises the event elsewhere, without subscribing?

Comment: @Le-royStaines when dealing with the invocation of async functions within  non `Task` functions this is the only available option. Check the link in the answer to understand why.